# Doubts on Providing Up Navigation

Tags: java, android

I would like to provide UP navigation in my app, but i do not understand: how to do it if i have some activities without static parent activity (it can be run from different activities).

For example, i have "Main activity", "Activity1", "Activity2" and "Setting Activity":

- Main Activity - does not have parent activity
- Activity1, Activity2 - the parent activity is "Main Activity"
- Setting Activity - also, does not have parent activity, can be run from "Main activity", "Activity1" and "Activity2".

To provide UP navigation (according to the Google documentation) there are 3 steps:

1. To declare which activity is the appropriate parent for each activity

   ```
   <application ... >
       ...
   <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
   <activity
       android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
       ...
   </activity>
   <!-- A child of the main activity -->
   <activity
       android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
       android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
       <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
   </activity>
   </application>
   ```
2. To show "UP" button:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   }
   ```
3. To add a button click handler:

   ```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
       // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
       case android.R.id.home:
           NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
           return true;
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

QUESTIONS:

1. How can i declare parent activity for my "Setting Activity" (step 1)? Or I need to modify the button click handle (step 3)?
2. What difference between a launch mode "singleTop" and "standart"? Where do i need to put them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way of providing a parent activity as you described is useful when a non-root activity (every one but the main activity) can be started via an intent external to your application. For these activities, it's useful: a tap on up should be different than a tap on back (up: go back to the parent activity, back: go back in the history stack, so go back to the external activity for example).

For activities like your `SettingsActivity`, you don't have a specific parent activity. You shouldn't use `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)`. Instead, just call `finish()`. You'll have the desired behavior when navigating inside your application, and I guess your `SettingsActivity` won't be called from somewhere else.

Regarding the difference between `singleTop` and `standard`: when you start an activity in standard mode, a new instance will be created. Which is probably what you want, hence the default. In `singleTop` mode, if an instance already exists in the same task, a new one won't be created, but the existing one will be reused. `onNewIntent()` will be called on it.

To specify a specific launch mode, you'll have to add an attribute to your activity's entry in the manifest. For your MainActivity, for example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

Note that `standard` is the default mode and doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: Can i used  onBackPressed()  instead of  finish() ?. So, if all activities of my app are not called from other apps I can use  onBackPressed()?

Comment: Why do you want to use `onBackPressed()` instead of `finish()`?

Comment: Really, I dont know... My users ask me to provide a back button and I thougt it was a correct way to emulate pressing on Back button.

Comment: Well, most of the time, both will have the same result: finish the activity. But `onBackPressed()` may be called in different situations. If you want to finish the activity, just call `finish()`, it's really simpler :-)

Comment: ok. So, if all activities of my app are not called from other apps or services I can use `finish()` and not declare "parent activity" in manifest?

Comment: You will have the same behavior, yes. But providing parent activity as a metadata is probably a better way to go: as it's just a metadata, it may be used for something else (but I don't know about any). Anyway, it's probably more future-proof.

Comment: understood. Could you please explain with more detail about "launch mode". Can I put `singleTop` to all my activities to prevent creation copies of them?

Comment: You can, but it should not be needed. Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: No, it is no specific problem. So, only for "MainActivity", or is it not needed too?

Comment: It's probably not needed. You should do without it, and think about adding a specific launchMode if you have a specific issue. Just stick to the standard as long as you can, you will avoid unnecessary potential complexity ;-)